# How to use Local storage in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, session-variables

I need to store data in the browser's session and retrieve the data until the session exits. How do you use local and session storage in Angular 2?

Answer (score 173):

The standard [`localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) should be available, just do e.g.:

```
localStorage.setItem('whatever', 'something');
```

It's [pretty widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

Note that you will need to add `"dom"` to the `"lib"` array in your `tsconfig.json` if you don't already have it.

Comment: typescript is throwing fits for me.  Did you find a way around this without having to use the npm listed for the other answers?

Comment: @Winnemucca *"throwing fits"* isn't a useful problem statement. I don't recall adding anything beyond what the Angular CLI includes.

Comment: I apologize.  I had to go inside of  my ts.config file to fix it.   "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ].   Did you already have "dom"  added?

Comment: @Winnemucca yes, that's set by the CLI. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('key');
localStorage.setItem('key','value');

Answer (score 130):

**How to store, retrieve & delete data from localStorage:**

```
// General syntax for storing data
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
// Also note that both the key & the value has to be strings. 
// So we stringify the value(if it's an object) before setting it.

// So, if you have an object that you want to save, stringify it like this

let data = {
  'token': 'token',
  'name': 'name'
};
localStorage.setItem('myLSkey', JSON.stringify(data));

// OR for individual key-value pairs
localStorage.setItem('myLSkey', JSON.stringify({
  'token': 'token',
  'name': 'name'
}));

// To retrieve the data & save it to an existing variable
data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myLSkey'));

// To remove a value/item from localStorage
localStorage.removeItem("myLSkey");
```

> **Tips**: 
> You **can also use a package for your angular app**, that is based on
> native localStorage API (that we are using above) to achieve this and
> you don't have to worry about stringify and parse. Check out this
> package for angular 5 and above. [@ngx-pwa/local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage) 
> You can also do a quick google search for maybe,**angular local
> storage**, & find a package that has even more Github stars etc.

Check out this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) to know more about Web Storage API.

Comment: Thanks for the JSON parsing tips!

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: I wish i could upvote this answer more than once. I realised that as my value is a boolean, I need to stringify it in order to set the local storage value.

Comment: For Angular 8, you can also check this simpler package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cedx/ngx-webstorage

Answer (score 44):

**Save into LocalStorage:**

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

For objects with properties:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Get From Local Storage:**

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```

For objects:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

**localStorage Object will save data as string and retrieve as string**. You need to Parse desired output
        if value is object stored as string.
e.g. `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('key'));`

*It is better to use framework provided localStroage instead of 3rd party library localStorageService or anything else because it reduces your project size.*

Answer (score 31):

Here is an example of a simple service, that uses localStorage to persist data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PersistanceService {
  constructor() {}

  set(key: string, data: any): void {
    try {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error saving to localStorage', e);
    }
  }

  get(key: string) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error getting data from localStorage', e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

To use this services, provide it in some module in your app like normal, for example in core module. Then use like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeOtherService {

  constructor(private persister: PersistanceService) {}

  someMethod() {
    const myData = {foo: 'bar'};
    persister.set('SOME_KEY', myData);
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    const myData = persister.get('SOME_KEY');
  }
}
```

Comment: great!, just made an example script with the same. url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/localstorage-angular-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 16):

Use [Angular2 @LocalStorage](https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage) module, which is described as:

> This little Angular2/typescript decorator makes it super easy to save
>   and restore automatically a variable state in your directive (class
>   property) using HTML5' LocalStorage.

If you need to use cookies, you should take a look at:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie

Comment: This doesn't currently have a person maintaining it.

Comment: The successor to the angular2-cookie project is ngx-cookie https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie

Comment: There is maintained and more powerful (e.g. listening for storage changes, support for cookies and temporary memory) [`ngx-store`](https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store) library compatible with `angular2-localstorage`

Answer (score 11):

You can also consider using library maintained by me: **[ngx-store](https://github.com/zoomsphere/ngx-store)** (`npm i ngx-store`)

It makes working with localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies incredibly easy. There are a few supported methods to manipulate the data:

1) **Decorator:**

```
export class SomeComponent {
  @LocalStorage() items: Array<string> = [];

  addItem(item: string) {
    this.items.push(item);
    console.log('current items:', this.items);
    // and that's all: parsing and saving is made by the lib in the background 
  }
}
```

Variables stored by decorators can be also shared across different classes - there is also `@TempStorage()` (with an alias of `@SharedStorage()`)) decorator designed for it.

2) **Simple service methods:**

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

  public saveSettings(settings: SettingsInterface) {
    this.localStorageService.set('settings', settings);
  }

  public clearStorage() {
    this.localStorageService.utility
      .forEach((value, key) => console.log('clearing ', key));
    this.localStorageService.clear();
  }
}
```

3) **Builder pattern:**

```
interface ModuleSettings {
    viewType?: string;
    notificationsCount: number;
    displayName: string;
}

class ModuleService {
    constructor(public localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {}

    public get settings(): NgxResource<ModuleSettings> {
        return this.localStorageService
            .load(`userSettings`)
            .setPath(`modules`)
            .setDefaultValue({}) // we have to set {} as default value, because numeric `moduleId` would create an array 
            .appendPath(this.moduleId)
            .setDefaultValue({});
    }

    public saveModuleSettings(settings: ModuleSettings) {
        this.settings.save(settings);
    }

    public updateModuleSettings(settings: Partial<ModuleSettings>) {
        this.settings.update(settings);
    }
}
```

Another important thing is you can listen for (every) storage changes, e.g. (the code below uses RxJS v5 syntax):

```
this.localStorageService.observe()
  .filter(event => !event.isInternal)
  .subscribe((event) => {
    // events here are equal like would be in:
    // window.addEventListener('storage', (event) => {});
    // excluding sessionStorage events
    // and event.type will be set to 'localStorage' (instead of 'storage')
  });
```

`WebStorageService.observe()` returns a regular Observable, so you can zip, filter, bounce them etc.

I'm always open to hearing suggestions and questions helping me to improve this library and its documentation.

Comment: What is the difference between `decorators` vs `services` approach?

Comment: Mainly syntax, decorators are the easiest to use, best for prototyping. Services are irreplaceable for more advanced use cases - you can update exactly what you want, so it becomes easier with complex data structures and gives better performance.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, perfect work. Your library helped me a lot today! :)

Answer (score 10):

Local Storage Set Item

**Syntax:**

```
  localStorage.setItem(key,value);
  localStorage.getItem(key);
```

**Example:**

```
  localStorage.setItem("name","Muthu");
  if(localStorage){   //it checks browser support local storage or not
    let Name=localStorage.getItem("name");
    if(Name!=null){  //  it checks values here or not to the variable
       //do some stuff here...
    }
  }
```

also you can use

```
    localStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify("Muthu"));
```

Session Storage Set Item

**Syntax:**

```
  sessionStorage.setItem(key,value);
  sessionStorage.getItem(key);
```

**Example:**

```
  sessionStorage.setItem("name","Muthu");

  if(sessionStorage){ //it checks browser support session storage/not
    let Name=sessionStorage.getItem("name");

    if(Name!=null){  //  it checks values here or not to the variable
       //do some stuff here...
    }
  }
```

also you can use

```
   sessionStorage.setItem("name", JSON.stringify("Muthu"));
```

Store and Retrieve data easily

Answer (score 7):

As said above, should be: `localStorageService.set('key', 'value');` and `localStorageService.get('key');`

Comment: Its working for me on my angular 4 project and i want to thank to you for save my time.

Comment: have not found doc about  localStorageService on the api web, where i can find this?

Answer (score 7):

To store in `LocalStorage` :

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, data);
```

To remove an item from `LocalStorage` :

```
window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
```

To get an item from `LocalStorage` :

```
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```

You can only store a string in `LocalStorage`; if you have an object, first you have to convert it to string like the following:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And when you want to get an object from `LocalStorage` :

```
const result=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
```

**All Tips above are the same for `SessionStorage`.**

You can use the following service to work on `SessionStorage` and `LocalStorage`. All methods in the service :

```
getSession(key: string): any
setSession(key: string, value: any): void
removeSession(key: string): void
removeAllSessions(): void
getLocal(key: string): any
setLocal(key: string, value: any): void
removeLocal(key: string): void 
removeAllLocals(): void
```

Inject this service in your components, services and ...; Do not forget to register the service in your core module.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BrowserStorageService {

  getSession(key: string): any {
    const data = window.sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    if (data) {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  setSession(key: string, value: any): void {
    const data = value === undefined ? '' : JSON.stringify(value);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);
  }

  removeSession(key: string): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  removeAllSessions(): void {
    for (const key in window.sessionStorage) {
      if (window.sessionStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.removeSession(key);
      }
    }
  }

  getLocal(key: string): any {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (data) {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  setLocal(key: string, value: any): void {
    const data = value === undefined ? '' : JSON.stringify(value);
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, data);
  }

  removeLocal(key: string): void {
    window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
  }

  removeAllLocals(): void {
    for (const key in window.localStorage) {
      if (window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this.removeLocal(key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can easily use the localStorage for setting the data and receiving the data.

**Note:** it works with both angular2 and angular 4

```
//set the data
localStorage.setItem(key, value);   //syntax example
localStorage.setItem('tokenKey', response.json().token);

//get the data
localStorage.getItem('tokenKey')

//confirm if token is exist or not
return localStorage.getItem('tokenKey') != null;
```

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of set item is

```
localStorage.setItem(key,value);
```

The syntax of get item is

```
localStorage.getItem(key);
```

An example of this is:

```
localStorage.setItem('email','abc@gmail.com');
    let mail = localStorage.getItem("email");
    if(mail){ 
       console.log('your email id is', mail);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Really elegant solution are decorators. You can use them to mark variables you want to store.

```
export class SomeComponent {

  @LocalStorage
  public variableToBeStored: string;

}
```

[Example how to achieve it is in this article (my blog)](https://filipmolcik.com/angular-2-local-storage/)

Comment: Links can break. It's better to put the example directly into your answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

Install "angular-2-local-storage"

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
```

Comment: _"if you really need something to happen when something happens"_ :) from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage

Comment: This answer will be better if you can provide an example on how to use this LocalStorageService.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cyrilletuzi's **LocalStorage Asynchronous Angular 2+ Service**.

Install:

```
$ npm install --save @ngx-pwa/local-storage
```

Usage:

```javascript
// your.service.ts
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class YourService {
   constructor(private localStorage: LocalStorage) { }
}

// Syntax
this.localStorage
    .setItem('user', { firstName:'Henri', lastName:'Bergson' })
    .subscribe( () => {} );

this.localStorage
    .getItem<User>('user')
    .subscribe( (user) => { alert(user.firstName); /*should be 'Henri'*/ } );

this.localStorage
    .removeItem('user')
    .subscribe( () => {} );

// Simplified syntax
this.localStorage.setItemSubscribe('user', { firstName:'Henri', lastName:'Bergson' });
this.localStorage.removeItemSubscribe('user');
```

More info here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage
https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage

Comment: What's the point in making synchronous operation asynchronous?

Comment: I suppose to deal with large amounts of data without blocking the ui

Comment: But the operation has to be done synchronously under the hood anyway, hasn't it?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know... please, answer this to the author if you want, and let us know his response.

Comment: I think he just used the same code as for IndexedDB, which works asynchronously.

Comment: it is possible because in my project data is written in IndexedDB by default

Answer (score 2):

To set the item or object in local storage:

```
   localStorage.setItem('yourKey', 'yourValue');
```

To get the item or object in local storage, you must remember your key.

```
   let yourVariable = localStorage.getItem('yourKey');
```

To remove it from local storage:

```
   localStorage.removeItem('yourKey');
```

Answer (score 2):

install

```
npm install --save @ngx-pwa/local-storage
```

first of all you need to Install "angular-2-local-storage"

```
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
```

Save into LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

Get From Local Storage:

```
localStorage.getItem('key');
```