# Storing Objects in localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
[{name:"test", time:"Date 2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z"}]
```

I stored it in `localstorage` and when I retrieving data from `localstorage` I got the value:

```
[object, object]
```

How can I solve this issue?

**config.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class TokenManager {

  public tokenKey: string = 'app_token';

  constructor() { }    

  store(content) {
    var contentData;

    console.log("inside localstorsge store:", content);
    contentData = content.map(
      (data) => data.name
    )
    console.log("contentData:", contentData)
    localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey, content);
  }

  retrieve() {
    console.log("inside localstorage");
    let storedToken: any = localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);
    console.log("storedToken:", storedToken);//====> here this console is[object object]
    if (!storedToken) throw 'no token found';
    return storedToken;
  }

}
```

Comment: you tried this `JSON.stringify(storedToken)` ?

Comment: JSON.stringyfy the object before saving to localstorage and parse it back while retrieving with JSON.parse.

Comment: @Satpal what is OP ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: see this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589730/local-storage-in-angular-2/57635667#57635667

Answer (score 163, accepted):

local storage limited to handle only string key/value pairs you can do like below using `JSON.stringify` and while getting value `JSON.parse`

```
var testObject ={name:"test", time:"Date 2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z"};
```

Put the object into storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

Retrieve the object from storage:

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: it works fine thanks for your reply. but while mapping this i got each as string like effect: [ 
effect: { 
effect: " 
effect: n 
effect: a  
effect: m  
effect: e 
effect: " how can i solve this?

Comment: can you please update your question to figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot . It's working on my end

Answer (score 26):

it is a little late for answering, but I want to answer until future viewers can use it, javascript  use objects by reference, then when we store an object to localStorage, in real we store the address of object , not the content of object!
then if we want to store object content (absolutely we want), we should do like below:

store like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('my_item', JSON.stringify(my_object));
```

and use like this:

```
var my_object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('my_item'));
```

hope to be helpful :)

Answer (score 10):

You cannot store something without **String** Format.

**LocalStorage** always store key and value in string format.

That is why you should convert your data to string whatever it is *Array* or *Object*.

To Store data in localStorage first of all stringify it using **JSON.stringify()** method.

```
var myObj = [{name:"test", time:"Date 2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z"}];
localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Then when you want to retrieve data , you need to parse the String to Object again.

```
var getObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('item'));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to store objects in local storage with [localDataStorage](https://github.com/macmcmeans/localDataStorage), where you can transparently set/get any of the following "types": Array, Boolean, Date, Float, Integer, Null, Object or String.

[DISCLAIMER] I am the author of the utility [/DISCLAIMER]

Examples:

```
localDataStorage.set( 'key1', 'Belgian' )
localDataStorage.set( 'key2', 1200.0047 )
localDataStorage.set( 'key3', true )
localDataStorage.set( 'key4', { 'RSK' : [1,'3',5,'7',9] } )
localDataStorage.set( 'key5', null )

localDataStorage.get( 'key1' )   -->   'Belgian'
localDataStorage.get( 'key2' )   -->   1200.0047
localDataStorage.get( 'key3' )   -->   true
localDataStorage.get( 'key4' )   -->   Object {RSK: Array(5)}
localDataStorage.get( 'key5' )   -->   null
```

As you can see, the primitive values are respected. Now, in your case, we would do this:

```
>localDataStorage.set( 'testObject', { name : 'test', time : new Date( '2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z' ) } )
```

Note that you can plainly express the object. (All the stringamication is done in the background for you.) When we retreive the key, we get:

```
>localDataStorage.get( 'testObject' ) -->
>Object {name: "test", time: "2017-02-03T08:38:04.449Z"}
```