# Storing data into Local Storage after first fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to fetch data from an api. But my page keeps fetching the data from the api whenever the page loads. I tried to solve this issue using localStorage like below.

I try to load the data stored in the localStorage but whenever the data loads, the data appears as [object Object].  How can i get the elements (patient_name,patient_phone) from the response instead of showing [object Object].

PS: Beginner with React

**Component**

```
   componentDidMount()
{
    let patients = localStorage.getItem('patients');
     if(patients)
    {
            this.setState({
            patientData: patients
     })         
    console.log(JSON.stringify(patients));
    }
    else
    {
        this.getPatients();
     }
}

    getPatients(){
    return this.fetchPost().then(([response,json]) => {
       console.log(response);
       if(response.status === 200)
       {             
             this.setState({
             patientDetails: json.data.patient
          })
          localStorage.setItem('patients',json.data.patient)     
       }
    })
 }

     fetchPost(){
        const URL = 'http://domain:3000/api/';
        return fetch(URL, {method:'GET',headers:new Headers ({
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         .then(response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage saves the data is String key/value pairs format, so save before save data convert object in to string using

> JSON.stringify(json.data.patient)

On Save

```
localStorage.setItem('patients',JSON.stringify(json.data.patient))
```

On Retrive

```
let patients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('patients'));
```

[Storing Objects in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020577/storing-objects-in-localstorage)

Comment: i get the error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` at  `patientData: JSON.parse(patients)`

Answer (score 0):

The LocalStorage API requires that both the [key and value of entries stored are of the string type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#Parameters).

You could revise your code so that data saved to local storage is serialised with `JSON.stringify()` to a string during save, and then deserialised with `JSON.parse()` to restore the data from a string during load:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    try {

    /* Attempt to parse data */
    let patients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('patients'));
    if(patients)
    {
        this.setState({
           patientData: patients
        });
    } 
    catch(err) {
       if(err.name === 'SyntaxError') {
        /* If there was an error parsing the data, fetching it
        from server (which has the side effect of saving the data
        into local storage in the required format is successful */
        localStorage.clear();
        this.getPatients();
       }
    }
}

getPatients(){

    return this.fetchPost().then(([response,json]) => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status === 200)
        {             
            this.setState({
                patientDetails: json.data.patient
            })

            /* Use JSON.stringify to serialize the data to a string */
            localStorage.setItem('patients',JSON.stringify(json.data.patient))
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: i get the error `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` at  `patientData: JSON.parse(patients)`

Comment: @RoboPHP just updated answer - does that help?

Comment: no, this answer is working just like my code above...in the console.log(patients), i get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],

Comment: Seems like bad data stored from earlier development is the potential cause - just updated code with `localStorage.clear();` in the catch block. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I am not able to understand why you have `localStorage.clear();`  Besides that isn't solving the issue

Comment: Strange - the idea with `localStorage.clear()` is to reset the store state if the format of whatever there invalid. Can you please tell me what `console.log(localStorage.getItem('patients'))` produces on the console?