# Typescript: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myself')) returns [object Object] instead of the expected object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following User classes:

```
export class User {
    id: string;

    // personal information
    email: string;
    surname: string;
    lastname: string;
    postalcode: PostalCode;
    birthdate: Date;
    profilePicture: HTMLImageElement;

    roles: Tag[];
    skills: Tag[];

    // watchingUsers: User[]; // separate request

}

export class Tag {
    description: string;
    category: string;
}

export class PostalCode {
    id: number;
    postalcode: string;
    municipality: string;
    municipalitySubdivision: string;
    country: string;
    countrySubdivision: string;
    countrySecondarySubdivision: string;
    freeform: string;
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
}
```

I want to store a user object into the local storage using:

```
localStorage.setItem('myself', JSON.stringify(myself));
```

The object stored in the local storage after that is looking like:

```
{
"id": "4f596d36-751f-11eb-9439-0242ac130002",
"surname": "Daniel",
"lastname": "Jansen",
"postalcode": {
    "postalcode": "12345",
    "municipality": "Test City",
    "municipalitySubdivision": "Subdiv",
    "country": "Deutschland",
    "countrySubdivision": "Subdivision",
    "freeform": "12345 Test City",
    "latitude": 123,
    "longitude": 123
},
"birthdate": "1995-12-17T02:24:00.000Z",

"roles": [
    {
        "description": "Design",
        "category": "USER_ROLE"
    },
    {
        "description": "Marketing",
        "category": "USER_ROLE"
    }
],
"skills": [
    {
        "description": "Figma",
        "category": "USER_SKILL"
    },
    {
        "description": "MarketingTool",
        "category": "USER_SKILL"
    }
]
}
```

And I want to get it using:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myself'));
```

For storing the object it has complained about some circular issues because of the 'watchingUsers' field. Therefore I commented that out.

Problem:
Running console.log(obj) I only get the following output:

```
[object Object]
```

So of course I can't access the fields in the user class. Does anyone have an idea why this happens? How can I get the real User Object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Storing Objects in localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020577/storing-objects-in-localstorage)

Comment: No unfortunately not. The solution there is exactly what I am currently doing. Maybe I am disregarding something.

Comment: Seems like when you log the particular object, the default conversion from an object to string is displayed as "[object Object]". Although, you still be able to access the attributes of the particular object. I hope that below mentioned question may help you to sort out the problem. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750225/what-does-object-object-mean