# Change a value in .ts file and save it in app ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, save, local

My app stores data in a .ts file. A function allows to change a boolean value (displayed) in this file. Is there a way to save those changes in the file? I would like the values to be saved if the user close the app and re open it.

**cards.ts**

```
    export default
  {
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "question": "blabla",
        "answer": "blablabla",
        "hint": "blablablabla",
        "displayed": false,
...
      },
    ]
  };
```

**cards.interface.ts**

```
  export interface Card {
  id: string;
  question: string;
  answer: string;
  hint: string;
  displayed: boolean;
}
```

**function that change the value**

```
getRandom() {
    this.answerVisible = false;
    this.availableCards = this.cards.filter(card => !card.displayed);
    let rd = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.availableCards.length);
    this.randomCard = this.availableCards[rd];
    this.cards.find(card => card.id === this.randomCard.id).displayed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to push the data in the LocalStorage?

Comment: Consider using [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589730/local-storage-in-angular-2), as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage in which the data is persisted until the user manually clears the browser cache or until your web app clears the data.
It's recommended you to use **[Ionic Storage](http://Ionic%20Storage)** when working with Ionic Application  which uses `SQLite` When running in a native app context, and When running in the web or as a Progressive Web App, Storage will attempt to use `IndexedDB`, `WebSQL`, and `local storage`,

Usage:

```
npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

Register it in imports array of your root module

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Finally, inject it into any of your components or pages:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ...

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
}
```

PS:Refer the link for clear picture and usage

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use Ionic Storage following the instruction from the official documentation. It is set properly in app.modules.ts and my component but i have this error : **"Runtime error : storage is not define"**. In console : "Property "storage" is declared but never used". Any idea ?
Also, I don't really understand how I can use storage based on my configuration. How can I save properties from this particular object ?