# Can I mount a single angular component or view to a new window tab?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to open a new window and then mount a single component? similar to Reacts Portal?

I know I can `window.open('/path', '_blank');` but that reloads the entire application.

Really just want to load a single informational component in a new window by itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Angular component in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005119/how-to-open-a-angular-component-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: @dota2proThat isn't mounting a single component, that loads the entire app again

Comment: What is the need of opening a component without app ?

Comment: That only a portion is loaded and not a completely new app. Imagine you have a component that's just a styled h1 tag and you pass text to it. Can you open that component alone or do you have to load the entire bundle? My question is trying to open that single component, your answer is opening the entire bundle

Comment: how about routing ?map a url with that component