# Angular cannot redirect to a new Component using routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

I am building a small app, and somehow, it's not redirecting. I'm trying to open the **IntroComponent**, but nothing happens when I do click on my links, or I try to open it:

[image: example]

These are my pieces of code:

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-countries-select></app-countries-select>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CountriesSelectComponent } from './home/countries-select/countries-select.component';
import { IntroComponent } from './intro/intro.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'intro', component: IntroComponent },
  { path: 'countries-select', component: CountriesSelectComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/countries-select', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: CountriesSelectComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CountriesSelectComponent } from './home/countries-select/countries-select.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormComponent } from './form/form.component';
import { IntroComponent } from './intro/intro.component';
import { OptionsComponent } from './options/options.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CountriesSelectComponent,
    FormComponent,
    IntroComponent,
    OptionsComponent,
    AboutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**countries-select.component.html:**

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <h2 for="welcome">Welcome to Spain</h2>
  <p>Choose Your Country of Origin</p>

  <div>
    <ul class="list-group" [style.height.px]="innerHeight">
      <li *ngFor="let country of countriesList" class="list-group-item">
        <a routerLink="/intro"  routerLinkActive="active">
          <img class="countryImg" [src]="'/assets/img/countries/' + country.flag + '.png'" /> {{ country.name }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**intro.component.html:**

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <video poster="" id="v" playsinline autoplay webkit-playsinline (ended)="introEnded()">
    <source src="assets/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success text-right">Next</a>
</div>
```

Also, this is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/FANMixco/AsylumAssistant/tree/basic-forms-UIs

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a Angular component in a new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52005119/how-to-open-a-angular-component-in-a-new-tab)

Comment: Can you remove the <app-countries-select></app-countries-select> from app.component.html and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `app-countries-select` from the `app-component.html` and then replace that with a `router-outlet`

Also change the `[routerLink]="['intro']" to [routerLink]="['/intro']"`

Comment: Thank Lakindu, but it duplicated the component for any reason and still didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean it duplicated? Can you attach a screen shot

Comment: Are you saying it duplicated the `CountriesSelectComponent`?

Comment: This is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81c0c.jpg

Comment: can you show me the URL once you click the flag?

Comment: In your countries select component, go to the template and change this ` <a routerLink="/intro"  routerLinkActive="active">` to  `<a routerLink="intro"  routerLinkActive="active">`

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: I committed the code: https://github.com/FANMixco/AsylumAssistant/tree/basic-forms-UIs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228134/discussion-between-lakindu-hewawasam-and-federico-navarrete).

Comment: Maybe you should add: Change the [routerLink]="['intro']" to [routerLink]="['/intro']"

Answer (score 0):

I tried building your app in my local and found that everything is working fine.
Maybe because you are putting `CountriesSelectComponent` on top of `app.component.html` so you didn't realize the intro component appears below.

If that is not your intention, just remove `<app-countries-select></app-countries-select>` from the `app.component.html`.
[image]

Comment: Hi Kien, did you download the branch? Because this is not my view. This should be another view the one below.

Comment: I built it from your `basic-forms-UIs` branch. This is my view when I click on `/intro` and scroll to the bottom.